# Teradata: Error 2621 while converting the value - how to find bad characters?

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to convert `varchar` value into `NUMERIC` and receive below error.

> Error 2621: Bad characters in format or data of (variable_name)

I want to remove the rows with those bad characters and keep only convertable ones.

How to do that in Teradata? Does Teradata have some function to do that? (something like `PRXMATCH` in SAS)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply `TO_NUMBER` which returns NULL for bad data points:

```
TO_NUMBER(mycol)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use regular expressions, you can use `translate`.  In Oracle, I would write this as:

```
select col
from t
where translate(col, 'x0123456789.', 'x') is not null and
      col not like '%.%.%';
```

I think Teradata has a more sensible policy on empty strings, so it would look like:

```
select col
from t
where otranslate(col, '0123456789.', '') <> '' and
      col not like '%.%.%';
```

Of course, remove the `.` if you only want integers.

Comment: Tried your code and receive error 3706 :( - this part doe not work: [translate(col, '0123456789.', '') <> ''] Is there some other way? What do you mean "If you don't use regular expressions..."? I'm ready to use anything :)

Comment: I believe in Teradata, `OTRANSLATE()` is the function you wish to use.

Comment: @GrigoryP . . . It depends on your version of Teradata.